# Do I need to include library dependencies again in my project for the .libs which are already included in the library I am statically linking with

Tags: c++, static-libraries, static-linking, visual-c++-2010

I have a library file : Accept.lib, 
This file has two library dependencies:

```
   AcceptSalary.lib and 
   AcceptDesignation.lib.
```

I have one exe project:

```
   AcceptAndDisplay.exe,
```

where I want to call method from :

```
   Accept.lib.
```

Now for static linking with Accept.lib, do I needed to include AcceptSalary.lib and AcceptDesignation.lib dependencies also in my project AcceptAndDisplay.exe?
If yes why it is needed to add again?

Comment: Yes, you no need to add "AcceptSalary.lib" again, its object files will be included trough Accept.lib.